# How can I get Babel with transform-react-jsx to properly transform a component without module.exports(for ACE editor use)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, reactjs

First some background: I am trying to set up a interactive "Try It" for React-Clone I made a week ago for a coding challenge. For example here is one of the samples I am working on [Create Component](http://sampledemo-scgraph.rhcloud.com/try-out/level4)

Anyways, when I use Babel and Webpack or browserify the React-clone I made works just fine, as in below:

```
const Trends = EX.component({
 componentName: 'trends',
 componentRender: (props) => {
  return (
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>{props.ex_thing.stuff}</h2> 
    </div>
  )
 }
});
module.exports = Trends;
```

Parent component:

```
 const Trends   = require("./trends.js");

 <Trends ex_thing={anObject} />

 //compiles to: 

 Trends({ex_thing: anObject})
```

But! if I define the component without commonJS it compiles  into **EX.node("Trends", {ex_thing: anObject})**. FYI: **EX.node** is what I use for the React-Clone I made.

Here on Google drive I have two HTML files one that works called **works.html** and another that's broken **broken.html**, it requires zero set up, just click and open in Chrome [Two HTML files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0l3iDre1kZ4OW9FSlVFMUVhZHM?usp=sharing)

The only difference is that for works.html I don't write the component **NameTag** in JSX since it compiles it like a element rather than a function. The compiled code is logged in the console.

How can I get Babel to compile **NameTag** to **NameTag({ex_person:itm})** and not **EX.node('NameTag',{ex_person:itm} )** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opps:** Sorry everyone I am an idiot. I recently noticed that React transpiles components just like mine was.

For example a component like **Trends** in react compiles like this:

```
  React.createElement(Trends, { ex_thing: anObject });
```

So what I did was I changed the function that creates the vDom to check if the Tagname is actually a function here:

```
NodeMap.prototype.node = (type, props = {}, ...nested) => {
  if (typeof type === "function") {
    return type(props);
  }
 nested = nested ? smoothNested(nested) : [];
 return {
   type,
   props,
   nested
 };
}
```

Now the **broken.html** works!